# How to say "at first sight"?

Tags: translation

How to translate "at first sight", for example in the sentence (no need to translate the whole thing): "at first sight, one might think that there is no life on the exoplanet, but after closer examination..."?

Comment: A google translate would even suffice, it doesn't seem that you've done any work to look up any of these answers yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

初看

头一眼看

一见之下

乍看

一见就

take your pick

Comment: Any idea what the most common is in Mandarin as used in Taiwan?

Comment: probably just 一看.....

Answer (score 1):

乍看之下 I think is most common here. I'm from Taiwan.

Answer (score 1):

初见 初见
or

第一眼 第一眼
or

第一次看到 第一次看到

第一次遇见 第一次遇见